# Prove that every extension of a finite field is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

In book by Roman 'Field Theory' it is written that it is straightforward that every extension of a finite field is normal. However I just cannot see it. Can you help me with this problem?

Thank

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the field $F$ is a subfield of $K$ with $K$ finite of order $q$, then the elements of $K$ are all roots of $x^q-x \in F[x]$, so this equation has $q$ (distinct) roots in $K$, and so  $K$ is its splitting field over $F$. So $K$ is a Galois extension of $F$.

Comment: I think this is the best argument.

Comment: But in this argument, we assume that extension of a finite field is also finite. Why is that?

Comment: @michael Can we assume that they're still algebraic extensions? If so, then see Jakob's answer for the explanation.

Comment: It depends on the definition of normal extension you are using. The one I am used to is that $K:F$ is normal if, whenever $K$ contains one root of $f \in F[x]$, then $f$ factorizes completely in $K[x]$. If $\alpha$ is the root in question, then $|F(\alpha):F|$ is finite, so $F(\alpha):F$ is normal by the above argument, and hence $f$ factorizes completely in $F(\alpha)[x]$. So $K:F$ is normal.

Comment: Would that mean that every normal extension is finite?

Comment: No. For example the field of all algebraic numbers is a normal extension of ${\mathbb Q}$ but is not a finite extension. It is less clear whether every normal extension needs to be algebraic: that seems to vary from boom to book. But since it is only the algebraic elements of the extension that determine whether or not it is normal, that is not so important.

Answer (score 4):

An (algebraic) field extension is normal if and only if it is the splitting field of a family of polynomials, i.e. if the extension $K/k$ contains an element $\alpha$, it also contains all conjugates of $\alpha$ in an algebraic closure. Thus, we can prove the extension is normal by proving this property for every element!
Now, consider an element $\alpha\in K$. Since $K$ is algebraic over $k$, there is a *finite* extension $k\subset L \subset K$ such that $\alpha \in L$. Now we'd like to prove that every *finite* extension of a finite field is normal. Why is that straightforward? For one, we can list all the finite extensions of finite fields, since we know all the finite fields...

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thought about what this would mean for infinite and possibly non-algebraic "extensions", so I'll pretend they don't exist.

From a finite extension of fields $E/F$ we get inequalities
$$
|\operatorname{Aut}(E/F)| \leq |\operatorname{Hom}_{F\text{-alg}}(E, \overline{F})| \leq [E:F].
$$
Normality means that the first inequality is actually an equality. The trick is that in this case it's easy to write $[E:F]$ elements of the automorphism group down.